# Using ViewPagerIndicator (viewpager) with multiple webview 's

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-viewpager

I have this (noob?) question, but i just can't figure it out for many hours now.

I'm using ViewPagerIndicator (based on ViewPager). I need to have 3 pages, each of them containing a web view with specific URL..

How can I get this running? All my attempts end with a situaltion, when I have 3 pages with ONE and THE SAME url loaded. I tried many approaches - but my understanding of the code seems to lack some basics.

my code:

```
public class WebPagerProfileActivity extends Activity {

private ViewPager awesomePager;
private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = 3;
private Context context;
private ViewPagerAdapter awesomeAdapter;
LayoutInflater inflater ;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);setContentView(R.layout.webpagerprofile);
context = this;

inflater = (LayoutInflater)
        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

awesomeAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(context);
awesomePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById( R.id.indicator );

awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);
indicator.setViewPager( awesomePager );}
```

and the adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements TitleProvider

{ private static String[] titles = new String[]
{
    "Profile",
    "Friends",
    "Statistics"
};
private final Context context;

public ViewPagerAdapter( Context context )
{
    this.context = context;
}

//@Override
public String getTitle( int position )
{
    return titles[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return titles.length;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem( View pager, int position )
{
    View layout = null; 


    switch (position) {
    case 0: {
        LayoutInflater mInflater =  (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout  = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.webprofile, null);

    WebView mainContent = (WebView)layout.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mainContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mainContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mainContent.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mainContent.requestFocusFromTouch();
    mainContent.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mainContent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mainContent.loadUrl("http://www.wp.pl");
    }

    case 1: {        LayoutInflater mInflater =  (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout  = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.webfriends, null);

    WebView mainContent = (WebView)layout.findViewById(R.id.webviewfriends);
    mainContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mainContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mainContent.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mainContent.requestFocusFromTouch();
    mainContent.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mainContent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mainContent.loadUrl("http://www.onet.pl");
    }

    case 2: {        LayoutInflater mInflater =  (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout  = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.webstatistics, null);

    WebView mainContent = (WebView)layout.findViewById(R.id.webviewstatistics);
    mainContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mainContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mainContent.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mainContent.requestFocusFromTouch();
    mainContent.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mainContent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mainContent.loadUrl("http://www.google.pl");
    }

    }

    ((ViewPager) pager).addView((View)layout,0);

    return layout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem( View pager, int position, Object view )
{
    //((ViewPager)pager).removeView( (WebView)view );
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject( View view, Object object )
{
    return view.equals( object );
}

@Override
public void finishUpdate( View view ) {}

@Override
public void restoreState( Parcelable p, ClassLoader c ) {}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void startUpdate( View view ) {}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `break` statements in your `switch` statement. As such, you're falling through all of your cases, recreating your content up to 3 times until you hit the bottom and you finally show the one with "http://www.google.pl". Add `break` like so:

```
switch (position) {
case 0: {
    LayoutInflater mInflater =  (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout  = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.webprofile, null);

    WebView mainContent = (WebView)layout.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mainContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mainContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mainContent.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mainContent.requestFocusFromTouch();
    mainContent.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mainContent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mainContent.loadUrl("http://www.wp.pl");
}
break;
```

Etc.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I hate such mistakes, I lost hours becouse of that, eh!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing breaks in your switch.  They're cascading down to the last one on all cases.  You need to break after each one.